# When creating a 3D surface in Python using Mayavi or PyVista how do I avoid filling holes/openings?

Tags: python, mayavi, pyvista

[Issue with Pyvista filling area that shouldn't be filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUVrZ.jpg)

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import pyvista as pv


mpl.use("Qt5Agg")
mpl.rcParams["toolbar"] = "None"  # Get rid of toolbar


def xy_waveguide_contour(throat, x_waveguide, ellipse_x):
    x_initial = (throat + (x_waveguide * (ellipse_x - throat))) / 2

    return x_initial


def xy_waveguide_contour_x2(throat, x_waveguide, ellipse_x):
    x_initial = (throat + (x_waveguide * (ellipse_x - throat)))

    return x_initial


def z_waveguide_contour(x_array, depth_factor, angle_factor, throat):
    angle_factor = angle_factor / 10000

    x_prime = x_array - (throat / 2)

    z = (x_prime / angle_factor) ** (1 / depth_factor)

    return z


def ellipse_contour(a, b):
    a = a / 2
    b = b / 2
    ellipse_steps = np.linspace(0, 0.5 * math.pi, 100)
    x_ellipse_array = np.array([])
    y_ellipse_array = np.array([])
    for h in range(100):
        x_ellipse_array = np.append(x_ellipse_array, a * np.cos(ellipse_steps[h]))
        y_ellipse_array = np.append(y_ellipse_array, b * np.sin(ellipse_steps[h]))
    return x_ellipse_array, y_ellipse_array


def circle_contour(throat):
    throat = (throat / 2)
    circle_steps = np.linspace(0, 0.5 * math.pi, 100)
    x_circle_array = np.array([])
    y_circle_array = np.array([])
    for j in range(100):
        x_circle_array = np.append(x_circle_array, throat * np.cos(circle_steps[j]))
        y_circle_array = np.append(y_circle_array, throat * np.sin(circle_steps[j]))
    return x_circle_array, y_circle_array


waveguide_throat = 30

ellipse_x = 250
ellipse_y = 150
depth_fact = 4
angle_fact = 40

# Total steps = 100
array_length = 100

xy_steps = np.linspace(0, 1, array_length)

# initialize x, y, z, and zero array
x_array = np.array([])
y_array = np.array([])
z_array = np.array([])
xsub_array = np.array([])
ysub_array = np.array([])
zero_array = np.zeros([array_length])

# calculate hor(x), ver(y), and height(z) contour data and add into array
for i in range(array_length):
    x_array = np.append(x_array, xy_waveguide_contour(waveguide_throat, xy_steps[i], ellipse_x))
    y_array = np.append(y_array, xy_waveguide_contour(waveguide_throat, xy_steps[i], ellipse_y))

    z_array = np.append(z_array, z_waveguide_contour(x_array[i], depth_fact, angle_fact, waveguide_throat))

# calculate data for ellipse
x_ellipse_data, y_ellipse_data = ellipse_contour(ellipse_x, ellipse_y)

# grab last point from z_array and make entire array same value to define height of ellipse/waveguide
ellipse_height = z_array[array_length - 1]

ellipse_z = np.full(shape=array_length, fill_value=ellipse_height)

# Calculate data for throat
circle_x, circle_y = circle_contour(waveguide_throat)


for j in range(0, array_length, 20):
    for i in range(array_length):

        xsub_array = np.append(xsub_array, xy_waveguide_contour_x2(circle_x[j], xy_steps[i], x_ellipse_data[j]))
        ysub_array = np.append(ysub_array, xy_waveguide_contour_x2(circle_y[j], xy_steps[i], y_ellipse_data[j]))

# X = np.concatenate((circle_x, x_ellipse_data, x_array, zero_array))
# Y = np.concatenate((circle_y, y_ellipse_data, zero_array, y_array))
# Z = np.concatenate((zero_array, ellipse_z, z_array, z_array))

# Reshape arrays into 1 column, multiple rows
x_array = x_array.reshape(-1, 1)
y_array = y_array.reshape(-1, 1)
z_array = z_array.reshape(-1, 1)
ellipse_z = ellipse_z.reshape(-1, 1)
x_ellipse_data = x_ellipse_data.reshape(-1, 1)
y_ellipse_data = y_ellipse_data.reshape(-1, 1)
circle_x = circle_x.reshape(-1, 1)
circle_y = circle_y.reshape(-1, 1)
zero_array = zero_array.reshape(-1, 1)
xsub_array = xsub_array.reshape(-1, 1)
ysub_array = ysub_array.reshape(-1, 1)

# save arrays to text

X = np.concatenate((circle_x, x_ellipse_data, x_array, zero_array, xsub_array), axis=0)
Y = np.concatenate((circle_y, y_ellipse_data, zero_array, y_array, ysub_array), axis=0)
Z = np.concatenate((zero_array, ellipse_z, z_array, z_array, z_array, z_array, z_array, z_array, z_array), axis=0)


xyz = np.concatenate((X, Y, Z), axis=1)

cloud = pv.PolyData(xyz)
surf = cloud.delaunay_2d()
surf.plot()
```

I am trying to create a 3D surface using pyvista (Have also tried Mayavi), whever I perform a delaunay_2D mesh to create the surface, the action performed closes the opening of this surface that should still be open. I would really appreciate anyone's help regarding this issue.

Edit: Added an updated code and removed plenty of code that did not pertain to this this question.

Comment: Please try to make your question self-contained by including all relevant code and data in it (rather than linking to pastebin). What are you trying to do? Do you have points defining the outline of a concave 3d shape, and you want to fill that in to get a full surface? What is that 3d shape?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I am plotting a total of 8 contours that form 1/4 of a waveguide. I am trying to plot the points in a 3D space and then creating a 3D surface from those points. The points define an outline plus 4 interior curves.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, any chance you could help me with this issue?

Comment: I could... but your question has insufficient code to help, and the pastebin you linked has way too much code and it's incomplete. If you [edit] your question with the minimum necessary to play with the problem (see also [mcve]) I can try taking a look.

Comment: @AndrasDeak , okay I updated the code. Everything there is needed to see the error in question and play with the code. These are the input variables: 
waveguide_throat
ellipse_x 
ellipse_y 
depth_fact
angle_fact 

You can leave these alone for now, its mainly the surface creation that I am having an issue with

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I updated everything in a new question. any chance you could take a look? I can't figure this out for the life of me

Comment: I'm aware of your new question, I'm the one who closed this one as a duplicate of the new one. I took a look a week ago, but I couldn't find an easy solution. Passing an `alpha` parameter to `delaunay_2d` gets you most of the way, but there are still fringes at the edges that you would want to avoid. And it seems to me that extrusion is not applicable here. My best guess would be to formulate your surface as a (2d) structured grid, for which we'd have to come up with a parametrised function of the surface. It probably wouldn't be too hard, but I haven't had time to look into this since.